# tkinter: ошибка NameError: name 'todolist' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

При нажатии на кнопку `save` и `delete` появляется ошибка "NameError: name 'todolist' is not defined"

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import filedialog

win =Tk()
win.geometry('300x300')
win.title('Registries')
win.resizable(False,False)


def clear():
  todolist.delete(0.0,END)


def Save():
  global todolist
  text = todolist.get(0.0,END)
  file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(title='Save name',filetypes=(('txt files','*.txt')('allfiles','*.*')))
  if file:
    file.write(text)


def Create_a_reestr():

  create_win = Tk()
  create_win.geometry('500x500')
  create_win.title('Create a registry')

  todolist = Text(create_win,width=50,height=20)
  todolist.place(x=50,y=20)

  save = Button(create_win,text='Save',bg='white',fg='black',width=25,height=2,command=Save)
  save.place(x=165,y=380)

  delete = Button(create_win,text='Delet text',bg='white',fg='black',width=25,height=2,command=clear)
  delete.place(x=165,y=430)

  create_win.mainloop()


create_reestr = Button(text='Create reestr',bg='white',fg = 'black',width=20,command=Create_a_reestr)
create_reestr.place(x=85,y=100)


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Так у вас `todolist` - это локальная переменная в функции `Create_a_reestr`. С чего вы решили, что остальные функции должны её видеть? Объявляйте её `global` там где присваиваете ей значение.

Answer (score 0):

Объясню, у вас `todolist` локальная переменная функции `Create_a_reestr`. Чтобы она стало глобальной, ее необходимо объявить до вызова функций. Вообще, лучше не заводить глобальных переменных, но ладно)
В общем вот ваш код, исправил еще ошибку с типами файлов:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

win = Tk()
win.geometry('300x300')
win.title('Registries')
win.resizable(False, False)


def clear():
    global todolist
    todolist.delete(0.0, END)


def Save():
    global todolist
    text = todolist.get(0.0, END)
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(title='Save name', filetypes=[('txt files', '*.txt'), ('allfiles', '*.*')])
    if file:
        file.write(text)


def Create_a_reestr():
    global todolist
    create_win = Tk()
    create_win.geometry('500x500')
    create_win.title('Create a registry')

    todolist = Text(create_win, width=50, height=20)
    todolist.place(x=50, y=20)

    save = Button(create_win, text='Save', bg='white', fg='black', width=25, height=2, command=Save)
    save.place(x=165, y=380)

    delete = Button(create_win, text='Delet text', bg='white', fg='black', width=25, height=2, command=clear)
    delete.place(x=165, y=430)

    create_win.mainloop()


todolist = None
create_reestr = Button(text='Create reestr', bg='white', fg='black', width=20, command=Create_a_reestr)
create_reestr.place(x=85, y=100)

win.mainloop()
```

И еще, Пожалуйста, никогда не называйте функции с большой буквы! обязательно почитайте о [pep8](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html) (руководство по написанию кода на Python)